# HP Switches in a ring

Tags: networking

Im struggling to find an answer to limitations of spanning tree in a ring network.

We have a network covering a large area that is in a ring format, Each node is fibre in and out and possibly one device on each switch. They cannot be cabled back to a single point as this covers such a large area.

So my question is is there a limit on how many switches that can be linked in to a ring with spanning tree? I know there is still 2 points of failure that could take out the entire network but this is a risk they are aware of.

Comment: OK great thanks, I will look in to that and see how we get on.

Comment: My bad, answer deleted. See http://serverfault.com/questions/457796/is-it-possible-to-include-switches-in-traceroute-hops